# Single word for a very small amount of time

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, time, french

In French, if I want to quantify a very small amount of time (but not fixed: it can be 5 ms or 0.1 ms) I can use a *pouième*. Is there an equivalent in English?

I'm not looking for an expression but for a standalone word.

EDIT : In fact, I need to create a [c++ class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_classes) which will measure time and be equal to a 1/600s. In French, `pouième` is a cute word which can means a [very small but undefined amount of time](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poui%C3%A8me). The issue is that I *must* write english code and that's why I would like to find a standalone equivalent.

Comment: It's just Too Broad. There are so many possibilities *(tick, mo[ment], instant, [split] second, jiffy, flash, trice, shake [of a lambs tail], etc.)*. Even with a precise context it wouldn't be possible to identify and upvote a *single, "correct" answer*. Added to which my understanding is *[pouième](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/poui%C3%A8me) = très petite quantité, très petite partie **de quelque chose***. So it's not particularly a "time-related" term in the first place. Perhaps more like a *dash, pinch, tad*

Comment: See [wink](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22500/how-long-is-a-wink/). Also (not exactly a duuplicate) [60th of a second](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51860/is-there-a-word-for-a-60th-of-a-second)

Comment: @samoth de l'emn?

Comment: I don't think you want to quantify an amount of time, because that would be an adjective, such as a "minute amount" ([see the second definition and pronunciation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minute)). Instead you want a word that means a very small amount of time, like "a bit".

Comment: After reading some of your comments below, it seems you're looking for a unit name... I'm having trouble understanding why you'd quantify an un-fixed unit of time.  What would the difference between 2.5  pouième and 4.1  pouième really mean?  How would that be useful or meaningful?  Answers to those questions might spur better answers.

Comment: Two shakes of a duck's tail?

Comment: You can't get smaller than the [Planck time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time).

Comment: I think we're going to need more context since few here know what pouième means. Is it like "un moment" where it just means a small amount of time, or are you talking about a quantifiable measure of time such as a couple milliseconds?

Comment: Ephemeral is used for fleeting time...

Comment: @Robusto, I don't need something that small... Gus, I'll define it myself (see edit)

Comment: As far as answering your question goes I think @choster has an excellent answer ('tick' is my preference in a software/programming context).  But when naming your class you might want to consider 'TimeUnit' which is more general.  Taking it further you might want to make the Tick or TimeUnit just a part of your class and name the class 'Clock' or 'Timer' since you expicitly stated that you are creating a class that measures time instead of just representing an amount of time.

Comment: I was being facetious. Obviously *no one* would need that except possibly a physicist.

Comment: **In computing "Tick" is indisputably the correct term to use.** To show the size of a tick and allow conversion to different units, some quantity like `TicksPerSecond` or `NanosecondsPerTick` is required.

Comment: Where does that factor 600 come from? For example if it's derived from having 60 fps, one could call it deciframe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it hits a number of close reasons: it is unclear, it is asking for a programming variable name, correctness is only by opinion.

Comment: This is Australian slang, and hilarious; but "poofteenth" is the word you're actually looking for.  From Urban Dictionary we get: "...Infinitesimally small amount, smaller than a pinch..." OR "Two-fifths of fuck-all"
Usage: "... missed it by a poofteenth"

Comment: Consider transferring the question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *blink of an eye* and *a split second* come to mind.

**Edit:** If you insist on a single word, you'll have to go with an *instant*, or get creative and change the sentence structure to accommodate a different part of speech, like *momentar(il)y*.

Comment: Rigth, but do you have it in one word?

Comment: Why does it have to be one word?

Comment: Because I'm going to use it as a unit

Comment: A unit can be any number of words. "A big tasty burger with jalapeños" can be a unit, and you won't be able to find a single-word substitute.

Comment: @Samoth: And I think you should add that *pouième* is a colloquial term and not a scientific term.

Comment: @Reg 'Units' are usually seen as agreed quantities of measurement rather than unit helpings etc. (I'm working on 'split seconds': 5.3 split seconds later...)

Comment: @Samoth: RegDwight's French is pretty good so it'll help him knowing how the word has come about. It's formed from [*pou*](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/pou) to which suffix [*ième*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-i%C3%A8me)'s been added. It's really  technical jargon and not a scientific term at all. It's not literary either.

Comment: @Laure I'm not sure it's coming from here but that's not the point

Comment: I would probably avoid any of the "moment" variations.  A moment is 1.5 minutes.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan Yes, just like *aeon* means a billion years, *epoch* means 1 million years, and *jiffy* means one unit of Planck time. Except when they don't..

Comment: @dotsamuelswan Says who?  Nobody has used that definition of "moment" for centuries.  Most dictionaries list it as a "historical" or "medieval" usage, not current.  By current usage, it just means a very short period of time, possibly synonymous with "instant".

Comment: @choster Fair enough.

Answer (score 32):

One can take a *[moment](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/moment)* or an *[instant](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/instant_2)* to indicate a short amount of time; depending on context this may mean a fraction of a second, several minutes, or a period of years:

> The doctor will be out in a moment.
>
> Neo-swing enjoyed a moment of mainstream popularity in the 1990s.

Something which is almost instantaneous is done in a *flash*, *blink*, or *twinkle*, by metaphor to a lighthouse, eye, or star respectively. I would consider these words too informal to use in business or technical settings, however. Even more casual is *[jiffy](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/jiffy)* or *jiff*, which I would only use in very familiar settings or to children: *Don't cry, little girl, your mommy will be here in a jiffy.*

If the amount of time will not vary, I might suggest *tick*, representing the smallest movement of a clock, but undefined. Of course, there is a risk that *tick* could be misinterpreted as a literal second or a minute. In spoken language, conversely, *second* or *minute* do not always represent literal amounts of time; *I'll be back in a second* or *It'll take a minute to get there* simply mean a short time. This is extended further in expressions such as the *five-minute rule* or *fifteen minutes of fame*.

As noted in various comments, these terms may have specific definitions within certain domains, for example *[moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28time%29)*, *[jiffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_%28time%29)*, *[tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*, *[instant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant)*, and *[shake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_%28unit%29)* on the small scale, and terms like *age*, *era*, *eon*, *epoch*, and so on at macro scales. Take appropriate care. Of course, no matter how short a time is involved, you'll have someone complaining that it takes *forever*.

Comment: +1 for tick, that is used  for a very short undefined amount time, can only be used for time but since it's OP's request it fits perfectly IMHO.

Comment: Jiffy actually has [technical meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_(time)#Uses) in some contexts. If you wanted to use it with an indeterminate meaning, you'd need to make sure to avoid those.

Comment: 'Tick' also has two technical meanings in the world of Microsoft programming - either 100ns (DateTime.ticks) or ' smallest amount of time the stopwatch is capable of resolving'.

Comment: Jiffy sounds dated to me, and so does tick.

Comment: Cautionary note - Jiffy Condoms used to exist as a brand in the UK, and, unfortunately, I still stifle a giggle when I hear people use the word... damn, my lavatorial sense of humour is immature sometimes. Still, the point is that you should be selective in where you use this. (they had the most fantastic commercials though)

Comment: Technically speaking, the definition of "instant" is no time at all, so that doesn't quite fit the bill if we're being pedantic. Of course it is often used colloquially in that manner.

Comment: +1 for *moment*, that's the word that sprung to my mind as well. *tick* is used in software for a similar purpose so would fit the OP's purpose well if they didn't mind a more casual word.

Answer (score 7):

I would say they are colloquial, but I have always like *tad* or *mite*

Comment: +1 Both seem to be good equivalents for the French *pouième*. Colloquial, one word, undefined can be used for time, but not exclusively.

Comment: Maybe I think of *nit* for similar reasons ...

Comment: I've never heard those words used to represent a small amount of time ("I'll be with you in a mite/tad"?). To me they're equivalent to 'a little bit', i.e. "That wallpaper's a tad ugly, don't you think?"

Answer (score 6):

The nuclear weapons people and electronic engineers use *[shake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_%28unit%29)* for a period of ten nanoseconds; this is from the expression *two shakes of a lamb's tail*, meaning a short period of time. Ten nanoseconds is a convenient measure of time for these applications.

Comment: I'm an electronic engineer, and frequently speak of nanoseconds with a somewhat intelligent look on my face, but have never heard of a "shake" in that context. Is it perhaps a right-Pondian usage?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, beats me. I am not in either of those trades; this is just a piece of useless data cluttering up my head.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Are you susceptible to EMI? Or you probably mean you are an ***electronics*** engineer?

Answer (score 4):

[*Jiffy*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jiffy), to me, seems to be the most appropriate word.

It means:

> [a very short time](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jiffy)

Comment: Did that ... *Pop* into your mind?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Honestly? Yes. The moment I read the question I knew I had a word for it. Didn't look at any of the answer. And yes *jiffy* did *pop*. But if I had completely read choster's answer I wouldn't have posted this answer. Thinking of deleting.

Comment: [ruining the joke] -- perhaps yr not a US citizen over 40 years old: Jiffy Pop was a staple snack of many households once upon a time.

Comment: My sincere apologies for that. Killjoy. And yes, you guessed it right.

Comment: Cautionary note: Technically, I think Jiffy is the perfect word, except for the fact that the word has been somewhat polluted since it was, for a while, a brand name of Condoms in the UK. Like saying "Rubber" in the USA when you mean "Eraser", if you say "Jiffy" in the UK you will get strange looks.

Comment: *Jiffy* is used for an ad hoc unit of time in the “fraction of a second” range in several computer-related contexts, so it is indeed a good choice here.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest possible unit of time known in physics is [planck time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time). Or, you can simply say planck. It's about 5.4 x 10^-44 seconds.

Comment: The O.P. asked for something that was not a fixed amount of time, but I suppose this suggestion could be adapted: _I'll be there in a few plancks!_ Of course, there's a good chance no one will know what you're talking about,but I suppose that just gives you something else to talk about.

Answer (score 4):

A word faster and shorter than a second?

> "I'll be with you in a **sec**."
>   "Hang on, I'll only be a sec!"
>   "OK, I'm on my way." "Great, see you in a sec!"
>     "Aren't you ready?"
>   "Just a sec!"

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/second) defines *sec* as being the abbreviation of second, and meaning *a brief interval of time; a moment.*

Answer (score 4):

There are some words that can easily be used to refer to a very small amount of time. The firsts to come to mind are: *trice*, *jiffy*, *flash*, *blink*. All those has been mentioned before...

So, I want to focus on another one: *heartbeat*.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language includes the definition:

> An instant: The police arrived at the scene in a heartbeat.

The Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary says:

> Idioms:
> in a heartbeat, Informal. enthusiastically and without hesitation; in an instant.

And the Oxford English Dictionary includes the following examples:

> laughter was only a heartbeat (very close to; on the verge of) from tears
>
> I’d do it again in a heartbeat (instantly; immediately)

---

When it about small quantities in general - aside from *heartbeat* and the words mentioned above - there are a few others to consider:

- *jot*: a very small amount.
- *soupçon* [Taken from french *souspeçon*]: a very small quantity of something.
- *whit*: a very small part or amount.
- *sprinkle*: a small quantity or amount of something scattered over an object or surface.
- *trace*: a very small quantity, especially one too small to be accurately measured.
- *trifle*: a small amount / (can be used as) a little; somewhat.
- *modicum*: a small quantity of a particular thing, especially something considered desirable or valuable.
- *pennyworth*: an amount of something that may be bought for a penny.

The use of some of these words may be a stretch, for example *pennyworth* specifically means what a penny can buy (even if it is not used like that), and both *trace* and *sprinkle* has other meaning that can be confusing. If you allow that you may consider:

- *dash* [as a noun]: a small quantity thrown in or mingled with a larger mass or amount.
- *shred*: a strip of material, such as paper, cloth, or food, that has been torn, cut, or scraped from something larger.
- *vestige*: a trace of something that is disappearing or no longer exists.
- *scrap*: a small piece or amount of something, especially one that is left over after the greater part has been used.

Of the mentioned words *soupçon* is dated to the point that my spell checker doesn't get it, the use *whit*, *trifle* and *pennyworth* is fading, *jot* use is steady, and *modicum* surprisingly common according to some sources.

Note: the above definitions are from the Oxford English Dictionary - except for *dash* that comes from the Dictionary of Collective Nouns and Group Terms, and also *trifle* and *modicum* that come from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary defines *nanosecond* is one thousand-millionth of a second, but its second definition is ‘an extremely short period of time’.

Comment: You're right but I forgot to mention that a `pouième` is undefined (ie you can't say a `pouième` is 5 ns) so I'm looking for a non-scientific term

Comment: "This'll be over in a nanosecond!" ~Zero, Marvel vs Capcom 3

Comment: Well, what you forgot to mention is that pouième is a funny slang word, not that this is 'undefined'. Nanosecond isn't funny at all.

Comment: Q: What is a nanosecond? A: It's the time it takes the driver in back of you at a traffic light to blow his horn when the light turns from red to green! Now THAT'S funny (IMO).

Comment: And an onosecond is the time it takes to realise you’ve mistakenly pressed the delete key.

Comment: Why not yoctosecond? :)

Answer (score 3):

I would think that "iota" would be good here, as in "Don't waste one iota thinking about it."

Comment: iota typically refers to content rather than time.

Comment: I don't think so. An [*iota*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iota) is *an extremely small amount*. In principle, an amount of *anything*, but I've never heard it used of ***time***.

Comment: Hmm...I've heard it before, but perhaps it's colloquial.

Comment: It is a quantity, so it fits.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iota

Comment: in the software context provided, iota was my first thought, because tick has a precise technical meaning

Answer (score 3):

If you mean conversationally, I would go with "a bit", "a moment" or even "a second" or "a minute" (no one will time you). Say your friend wanted to show you something online, or you're telling your mum you'll be at dinner in a small amount of time, you could use any of those words and tell them you'll "be there in a second." If you were calling your friend as you were driving to apologize for being late to a dinner engagement, you'd tell them you'll "be there in a bit" or "just a bit". These sound the most casual and conversational to me and most like something that a twenty-something would say.

If you mean in a technical written document, something to mean mere fractions of a second, I would use "a split second" even though it is multiple words.

In response to some of the other answers, a "jiffy" sounds dated to me, as "iota", a "plank" sounds too nerdy, and a "shake" is something my grandfather's generation would say.

Comment: Agree. No one would care if you make them wait longer or shorter than you intended to, since, there's no big difference. Also, if you tell someone to wait for "the word", or I will be done in "the word", you are probably lying. Because, you can't probably do anything meaningful in less than 5 seconds. I like "jiffy" though, but it means very fast.

Answer (score 2):

You might try "momentary" or "fleeting"?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the context. Pouième conveys the idea of a negligible quantity in comparison to a whole — and not just of time, at that.

The two examples from wiktionary:

> A un pouième près, ils sont tous d’accord sur ces vingt minutes.
>
> Un pouième de seconde.

Might translate to:

> Give or take minute details, they all agree on those twenty minutes.
>
> A fraction of a second.

The current top voted answer is not perfect imho… You could understand instant as a small moment, of course. But in the context where you'd actually mention a pouième in French, an instant would more typically refer to an infinitesimal point in time.

Methinks "a fraction [of]" conveys the idea better if you want to keep the humorous spirit of "pouième", else go with "instant" if time is the context you have in mind.

Comment: I like "a fraction of second". I'm not so sure about your translation of the first sentence; "Give or take a nitpick" doesn't seem right to my ears, nor does "agree over".

Comment: @aetheria: ya, true. Fixed, but I'll probably end up deleting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

How about "Stat"?  Nobody says "Get him to to the E.R., in a jiffy".

Comment: "Stat" typically acts as an adverb.

Comment: Good point.I also like "Now".  It can describe anything from a fraction of a second to a much broader period of time such as the current century.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a medieval notation where an *'atomus'* (or atom, literally 'not smaller than') was defined as the blink of an eye. It was thought that it was the smallest unit of time measurement.

The term was redefined rigorously as 1/376 of a temporal minute in the modern era as more robust measurement equipment became available.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is a small amount of time but it isn't indeterminate, it is a regular and fixed interval. "Tick" is the correct term to use in computing to mean "the resolution of the clock" or "the frequency of a timer/timed event".

It is not just used as milliseconds as in the GetTickCount function, it is used everywhere, for various amounts of time.

It is called a Tick in .Net datetime library. Here each one is 100 nanoseconds:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

In Posix it is called a tick. Here the time depends on the system "The number of clock ticks per second can be obtained using `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);` ": http://linux.die.net/man/2/times

Boost uses the term tick in the same sense as Posix: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_period

MIDI uses the term Tick: http://cnx.org/content/m15051/latest/

Tick is also used to mean timer resolution in .Net's System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, in the Timer class, and the DispatcherTimer class.

The only exception seems to be the FILETIME documentation which refers to 100-nanosecond Intervals.

Answer (score 1):

What about "snath" or a "tick"?

Comment: 'snath'? I've never heard of that.  Is there a specific meaning? Can you give a reference?

Answer (score 1):

As we strive for [smaller and smaller intervals of time](http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2012/explained-femtoseconds-and-attoseconds) we progress from

> **nanosecond**: one thousand millionth of a second

through

> **picosecond**: one million millionth of a second (American trillionth of a second)

to

> **femtosecond**: one thousand million millionth of a second (American quadrillionth of a second)

and finally

> **attosecond**: one million million millionth of a second (American pentrillionth of a second).

Technically **zeptoseconds** and **yoctosoeconds** exist as defined units of time smaller by further factors of 1,000 and 1,000,000 but those terms are too geeky even for me.

Comment: For more completeness, the list deserves **millisecond**: one thousandth of a second.

Comment: @martinf: **Millisecond** is too large and pedestrian to count as a *small* unit of time to a physicist. ;-)

Comment: Maybe, but the specs _were_ 5 ms to 0.1 ms

Comment: @martinf: Any lack of imagination by OP is not my responsibility.

Comment: All these are too specific OP since says he wants to qualify an  **undefined** and **non-scientific** term.

Answer (score -1):

A 90's slang pop-culture reference would be 'mmmbop' from 1997's one hit wonder band 'Hanson' from the song with the same title.

see http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/mmmbop

Just throwing it out there.